# Should I always use generics?

Tags: java, generics, testing, coding-style, junit

I created a unit test :

```
new Callable() {
@Override
public Object call() throws
         .....
```

I have received warning in Eclipse:

```
Callable is a raw type. References to generic type Callable<V> 
should be parameterized
```

Should I write code like:

```
new Callable<Object>()
```

for eliminating warning, or not?
It seems only junit test and there is no sense to add additional code...
Thanks.

Comment: If you care about testing (which you should), write your tests to the same standard as the rest of your code - they will need to be reliable and maintained too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your operation doesn't return a value (, or there's nothing meaningful to return). You should use `java.lang.Void` as type parameter.

```
new Callable<Void>() {

  public Void call() throws Exception {
    // do work
    return null; // <-- This statement is required.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's a good practice to avoid raw types and use generic types. Using `Callable<Object>` makes it clear that the Callable is intended to return any kind of Object. Using `Callable` doesn't make that clear.

Comment: most people like generics when they don't have to write the libraries where a lot of signatures come like `<? extends T>` or  `<? super T>` or `<R extends Reference<? extends T>> R foo(R ref)`. One of the reasons I usually have the raw types warning disabled (even though I am usually diligent putting up w/ the super verbose signatures) :D

Comment: Using Callable<Object> makes it clear that the Callable is intended to return any kind of Object. But it also can be confusing - I don't intend return anything. I use Callable only because it can throw exception so I can handle it in external code block.

Comment: Then make it a Callable<Void> as @MartinK shows in its answer, which makes it clear that the Callable doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

Runnable is a good substitute for Callable< Void >.